# Answerers Comments "Background Color"

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

Does anyone else think having answerers comments have their own background color like the OP does for any comment they make, make for better readability. Sometimes looking at comments (mostly) when there are many comments and you have to thumb through trying to see what comments the answerer posted can be hard to find other times it isn't that bad when theres very few comments.

If this were in place looking at a post you can automatically see the answerers comments as well as the OP's and if both are there you can see the conversation between them you can focus/know who's talking (OP, answerer or other user[s]).

Any comment from the OP or `owner` as the CSS states them as goes applies the following:

**CSS:**

```
.owner{
    background-color: #deedff;
    background-color: rgba(222, 237, 255, 0.4);
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
a.comment-user.owner {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**
[image]

---

The following is an example of what might answerers comments would look like.

**CSS:**

```
.answer{
    background-color: rgba(108, 0, 0, 0.17);
    /*change to what you want to suit each site*/
}
a.comment-user.owner, a.comment-user.answer {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**
[image: Answerers comments example]

Comment: The colors you've chosen as an example look *very* similar, and I'm not sure what colors *could* be chosen that would be distinguishable from each other whilst still fitting in to the site's theme.

Comment: I approve of the idea (even if I think serious work would be required to choose a good colour). I often read comment chains below answers and keep having to scroll up to check whether that commenter was in fact the answer's OP.